# UsinGoogle Vision with unity and getting "404. /v1/images:annotate was not found on this server

Tags: api, rest, unity-game-engine, google-vision

So basically all I want is for Google vision to identify an Image of mine...
I send the following request:
to: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=

With Data:

`{"parent":"", "requests":[ {"image":{"content":"<MY IMAGE>"}, "features":[ {"type":"LABEL_DETECTION", "maxResults":"1"} ]} ]}`

But for some reason the response I get is:

> 404. That’s an error.

The requested URL `/v1/images:annotate?key=AIzaSyCBqsHq5Ezvd8WVMnpHYWtptqxVXToLEds` was not found on this server.  That’s all we know.

What's wrong with this one?

Answer (score 0):

if you will use postman to end you receive " "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.","
So please renew the API key.